# Characters to Character Entities PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to use the Facebook share dialog with the redirect uri. However, because my URL has link parameters in it, it doesn't want to work properly and the link that actually gets shared on Facebook is missing params etc. How can I remedy this?

Link example: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=**APPID**&display=popup&href= **LINK COM/INDEX.PHP?PARAM=1&PARAM2=2**&redirect_uri= **LINK COM/INDEX.PHP?PARAM=1&PARAM2=2**

I saw something about htmlspecialchars() but it didn't work for me, or maybe I just don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: read the function name. **HTML**specialchars(). urls have NOTHING to do with html. try `urlencode()` instead, maybe.

Comment: This is why I'm asking here, because I'm not too familiar with PHP. can someone submit a code snippet for me to look at?

Comment: Please go read the manual on `urlencode` if it is unclear to you how that function works.

Comment: I tried that, it's very confusing. I tried looking up videos on it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the easy bullet-proof way to build this URL:

```
$share_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?'.http_build_query(
  array(
    'app_id' => 'APPID',
    'display' => 'popup',
    'href' => 'http://example.com/INDEX.PHP?PARAM=1&PARAM2=2',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/INDEX.PHP?PARAM=1&PARAM2=2',
  ),
  null,
  '&'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Is there a way to make the redirect_uri open up on the old window instead of the newly opened share window?

Comment: If you'd like to do that then it's better to either (1) open the Share Dialog URL in the main window or (2) use the JavaScript SDK and redirect the main window when your callback is called (after sharing).